# Does Entropy always increase in an isolated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Suppose I **isolate** a thermodynamic system and fix its Volume and Number of particles.

$\quad dV = dN = 0$

Also suppose that initially the system was in a Macrostate with very **small Multiplicity**. So I guess it will keep shifting to a more probable Macrostate.

$\quad dS > 0$

Does this mean that the total Thermal energy of such **isolated system** will increase with time?

$\quad TdS = dU$

Comment: Remember that in an isolated system the total energy cannot increase so your conclusion with respect to your equations is false. In this case $dU = 0$.

Comment: Remember that dQ=TdS only for a reversible process path.  This process is not reversible.  If you devise a reversible path between the initial and final states of this system, the heat exchange for that path will not be zero.

Comment: entropy is NOT heat but entropy *times* temperature IS heat/thermal energy/puissance motrice/etc.,... Mass is not energy but mass *times* gravitational potential IS energy, same with thermodynamics where the thermal "potential" is temperature and the thermal "mass" is entropy.

Comment: No. The simplest counter-example is a Schr"odinger particle in its ground state in a box potential. This ground state stays the same forever.

Answer (score 6):

> Does this mean that the total Thermal energy of such **isolated system** will increase with time?

No. Here is a cartoon answer to your question:

[image]

A box is divided into two parts, one that contains a gas, and one that is evacuated. The system is the gas plus the vacuum. It is closed, rigid and insulated, i.e. it is isolated. Suppose the wall between the two parts is a piston held in place by latches that can be removed. For easy math the gas is ideal.

- Move the wall to the new position in stat B: This can be done without the input of energy, just place latches to catch the piston in its new position. The expansion of the gas to its new volume is spontaneous and takes no energy, so its energy is the same as in A but its entropy is higher
- Let the gas expand to the next set of latches. Same thing: the energy stays the same and the entropy increases further.

If the gas is ideal its temperature stays constant with each expansion. What happens is that the volume is bigger, threfore more microstates are available.

If the gas is not ideal it temperature will change as there will be some redistribution of energy between kinetic and potential. Its total energy though will be the same in all states.

> What about $TdS = dQ$ then?

This equation applies to *reversible* paths but our process is irreversible.

Answer (score 3):

The equation $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN +...$ describes the difference in internal energy between two nearby equilibrium states whose configuration coordinates $S,V,N,..$ are apart by $dS, dV, dN, ...$ while having their respective intensive potentials, $T, -p, \mu, ...$ equal up to 1st order. An isolated system is characterized by having no exchange with its environment, none, that is $dS=0, dV=0, dN=0, ...$, hence $dU=0$

Comment: Then why do we say that Entropy of isolated system increases, just like Gibb's Free energy always decreases in a chemical process?

Comment: If you change the *internal* constraints then you can have a spontaneous internal rearrangement that does not affect the overall energy but internally increases the entropy until it reaches maximum at which point the system with the new internal constraints will have reached its new equilibrium. The simplest example is an externally isolated cylinder with an adiabatic fixed position internal separating wall. The two halves are in equilibrium and are isolated individually from everything else. Now remove the separation and observe the new equilibrium after mixing the gasses.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that the total Thermal energy of such **isolated system** will increase with time?

You already asserted that
$$\mathrm dV=0=\mathrm dN\tag1$$
and it cannot be called isolated without
$$\mathrm dU=0\tag2$$
so that, really, any
$$\mathrm dS>0\qquad\implies\qquad\mathrm dS=\mathrm dS_\text{irrev}\tag3$$
That is, the entropy increased by spontaneous internal irreversible generation, and *not* by reversible transfer of heat.

---

The really correct way to teach statistical thermodynamics, is to scrutinise the entropy function $S=S(U,V,N)$ rather than energy $U=U(S,V,N)$ that is the historical norm to do.

Comment: So what will happen in an isolated system undergoing 'spontaneous internal irreversible generation'? Will the Total Thermal energy increase with time?

Comment: @BraveDiva thermal energy is a vague term

Comment: There is no such thing as Total Thermal Energy. Carnot proved that you can keep converting heat to work, more than the total energy inside a system. Entropy is not heat.